# unable to scroll MKMapView.

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do an iOS app using Xcode 6.3 and swift. I use MKMapView for tracking user position. The problem is that if I scroll the map I immediately return to the user position. This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self      
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest   
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()                
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()                     

    theMap.delegate = self
    theMap.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
    theMap.zoomEnabled = true          
    theMap.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    theMap.scrollEnabled = true

}
```

and

```
func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {

    let spanX = 0.007
    let spanY = 0.007
    var newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: theMap.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
    theMap.setRegion(newRegion, animated: false)
    theMap.scrollEnabled = true

}
```

If I scroll the map, after 1 sec I return to the user position. Should I change setRegion method position?

Comment: MKCoordinateRegion(center: theMap.userLocation.coordinate this will return you to the user position.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to detect when you scroll the map, possibly by implementing the `mapView(_:regionWillChangeAnimated:)` method defined in `MKMapViewDelegate`. In this method you need to set the `userTrackingMode` property of your map view to `.None`. Your implementation will be called when the user pans or zooms your `theMap` variable. So you should strive to keep the implementation as lightweight as possible since it could be called many times for a single pan or zoom gesture.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    if you want to stop tracking the user {
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .None
    }
}
```

When you want to start following the user's location again, change that property back to either `.Follow` or `.FollowWithHeading`:

```
enum MKUserTrackingMode : Int {
    case None // the user's location is not followed
    case Follow // the map follows the user's location
    case FollowWithHeading // the map follows the user's location and heading
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ndmeriri. I solve my problem reading documentation. I put         "theMap.setRegion(newRegion, animated: false) method  in locationManager method and the add a map-tap-listener where I disable updating location with manager.stopUpdatingLocation() method.

Thanks!